# Relationship between performance and the number of call stack layers?

Tags: actionscript-3

Do the number of call stack layers affect performance, i.e. cause a performance hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no correlation with the depth.

While "chained" scopes do need to be traversed, this is related to *lexical scopes* and not call stacks. The cost of the call frame ("method call") should be constant -- and independent -- from the depth of the frame.

Happy coding.

Comment: ...this is a good example of why I should expand my vocabulary significantly.